# How do I set the value of a property via a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm trying to run a function inside a reducer function to calculate a cart total, but the value in the state object is the *function* and not the *result* of the function. After render, the result is displayed, but I cannot pass the object to other components (I'm using a context). How do I do it? Here is the code (assume that the values work, because they do).

I've tried setting it to the `const` to no avail. I've tried an anonymous function that *returns* the function's total, and it still doesn't work. I've also tried just calling the function.

```
  const reducer = (cart, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
  case("ADD_ITEM"):
    return {
      ...cart, 
      products: {
        ...cart.products,
        [action.payload.product.id]: {...action.payload.product} 
      },
      total: () => (cartTotal)
    }
  break

  case("REMOVE_ITEM"):
    delete cart.products[action.payload]
    return {
      ...cart,
      products: {
        ...cart.products
      },
      total: () => (cartTotal)
    }
  break

  case("CLEAR_CART"):
  return {
    cart: {
      ...initialState
    }
  }
  break
}
}
```

Here is the object:

```
cart: {
  products: [{}],
  total: 0
  }
```

Here is the function to return the total:

```
  const cartTotal = () => {
    const total = Object.values(cart.products).reduce((prev, curr) => {
      const currPrice = (curr.data.on_sale && curr.data.sale_price) ? curr.data.sale_price : curr.data.price
      return prev + currPrice
    }, 0)
    return total.toFixed(2)
  }
```

Right now, I'm passing the method that allows you to calculate the total, but it seems like it is unnecessary, as I'm watching the cart state and updating the *value* of total each time items are added/removed. How do I set the value of a property *inside* of the reducer function as the return of another helper function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you storing derived state, well, in state? This should be computed via a selector when reading your state out (*and/or passed to a custom Context provider*).

If you must store the total in state then you need to call the `cartTotal` function to be able to store its return value. Unfortunately this will only compute the cart total on the unupdated cart since you are currently in the function that returns the *new* cart state.

You can factor out the cart update so you have an updated cart products object, and with a small revision of `cartTotal` it can consume this updated cart products object and compute a total.

Example:

```
const cartTotal = (products) => {
  const total = Object.values(products).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const currPrice = (curr.data.on_sale && curr.data.sale_price) ? curr.data.sale_price : curr.data.price;
    return prev + currPrice;
  }, 0);
  return total.toFixed(2);
};
```

Cases

```
case "ADD_ITEM": {
  const { payload } = action;

  const products = {
    ...cart.products,
    [payload.product.id]: { ...payload.product },
  }

  return {
    ...cart, 
    products,
    total: cartTotal(products),
  }
  break;
}

case "REMOVE_ITEM": {
  const products = { ...cart.products };
  delete products[action.payload];
  return {
    ...cart,
    products,
    total: cartTotal(products),
  }
  break;
}
```

Comment: My thought was every time the cart changes, calculate the total and store it. The total is just the accumulation of all of the items that have been put in it

Comment: So should I remove the function and expose it in the context?

Comment: @JoelHager See step 3 of [thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state), and scroll down a bit, question 3 of a checklist reads as "Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your component? If so, it isn’t state." I don't really see why a "cartTotal" function would need to included in a Context, it's a utility function, either expose the cart state and run it through the function in the UI, or compute the total in the Context and expose the cart total.

Comment: I see. That's what I ended up doing 'as a bandaid' - but here I learn that it is the best practice. You learn something new every day! Thanks! I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @JoelHager React official docs are a pretty good resource. Years in and I still find nuggets of information. Many times I probably glossed over when less experienced because I just didn't have the base knowledge built up yet.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't occur to me. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `cartTotal` to calculate the value.

```
total: cartTotal()
```

Comment: I've tried it, and it gets the value, but when I access cart.total, it shows up as a function.

Comment: Because you save `total` is function. You need to update all to `total: cartTotal()`

Comment: I mentioned in my OP that I tried that and it does the same thing.